# Mono for Android: Spinner within a listview

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, spinner, android-spinner

I have a listview which is populated from a webservice using an ArrayAdapter.
The webservice provides me with all the data I need. Some are just plain textviews yet other alternate between EditText and spinners. I show them easily, also filling up the values where they're due in EditText fields.

The problem comes with filling up the value of the Spinner. Can I define an adapter within an adapter? Also my data comes from a webservice as an XML passed as a string.

My Spinner code so far inside my Adapter.cs:

```
if (item.FieldType == "OptionBOX")
    {
        Spinner SpinnerValue = (Spinner) view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinnerVal);
        SpinnerValue.Visibility = view.Visibility == ViewStates.Invisible ? ViewStates.Invisible : ViewStates.Visible;

        bool isReadOnly = bool.Parse(item.isReadOnly);

        if (isReadOnly == true)
        {
            SpinnerValue.Enabled = false;
            SpinnerValue.Focusable = false;
            SpinnerValue.FocusableInTouchMode = false;
        }
    }
```

My data for the spinner is within item.optbox_options.

A table from my XML for easier understanding:

```
<Table diffgr:id="Table5" msdata:rowOrder="4">
<IdRec>5</IdRec>
<FieldId>1026</FieldId>
<FieldDesc>stanje rezervoarja</FieldDesc>
<FieldType>ComboBOX</FieldType>
<isReadOnly>true</isReadOnly>
<FieldValue>6</FieldValue>
<FieldTextValue>2/4</FieldTextValue>
<OptBox_Options>
<Options><myOPT FieldValue="1" FieldTextValue="0"/><myOPT FieldValue="2" FieldTextValue="1/4"/><myOPT FieldValue="6" FieldTextValue="2/4"/><myOPT FieldValue="7" FieldTextValue="3/4"/><myOPT FieldValue="8" FieldTextValue="4/4"/></Options>
</OptBox_Options>
</Table>
```

So just to clarify my needs and wants:
Can I use an adapter within an adapter and if I can - how?
How can I display data from the OptBox_Options row? I need to display the value from the FieldTextValue column inside  in my spinners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved using:

```
List<string> entries = new List<string>();

String rawXML = item.OptBox_Options;

StringReader stream = null;
XmlTextReader reader = null;

DataSet xmlDS = new DataSet();
stream = new StringReader(rawXML);
// Load the XmlTextReader from the stream
reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
xmlDS.ReadXml(reader);

DataSet myOPTvalues = new DataSet();
myOPTvalues = xmlDS;

foreach (DataRow row in myOPTvalues.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    var optItem = new PrevzemSpin();
    optItem.FieldValue = row["FieldValue"].ToString();
    if (optItem.FieldValue.Equals("")) optItem.FieldValue = null;

    optItem.FieldTextValue = row["FieldTextValue"].ToString();
    if (optItem.FieldTextValue.Equals("")) optItem.FieldTextValue = null;

    entries.Add(optItem.FieldTextValue);
    SpinnerValue.Tag = optItem.FieldValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think that it is not possible to instantiate an `Adapter` somewhere inside your custom `Adapter` for your `ListView` to populate content inside of it? You can simply make the implementation of the `Adapter` for your `Spinner` outside of the `Adapter` for the `ListView`.

Then you just need to think out a decoupled way to pass data through the hierarchy of `Adapters` so that all levels get the data you want.

However I don't think the `ListView` design pattern is suited for this kind of interaction and you will probably have problems with touch events not being fired. I think an `ExpandableListView` would be a more sensible choice of design pattern for what you are trying to achieve, and will have a better usability.

You can find an example of an `ExpandableListView` here: [ExpandableListView Mono for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8674628/expandablelistview-mono-for-android)