# Mono for Android: XML data to spinner

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, spinner, android-spinner

**My XML Example:**

```
<Table diffgr:id="Table17" msdata:rowOrder="16">
    <IdRec>17</IdRec>
    <FieldId>1213</FieldId>
    <FieldDesc>Equipment</FieldDesc>
    <FieldType>OptionBOX</FieldType>
    <isReadOnly>false</isReadOnly>
    <FieldValue>388</FieldValue>
    <FieldTextValue>B - satisfactory</FieldTextValue>
    <OptBox_Options>
        <Options>
            <myOPT FieldValue="387" FieldTextValue="A - good"/>
            <myOPT FieldValue="388" FieldTextValue="B - satisfactory"/>
            <myOPT FieldValue="389" FieldTextValue="C - needs change"/>        
            <myOPT FieldValue="390" FieldTextValue="D - deal"/>
        </Options>
    </OptBox_Options>
</Table>
```

**My problem**
The above xml data comes from a webservice. I have no problem with any field other than OptBox_Options which is a field I need to use to populate my spinner. Ergo I need to get the string from OptBox_Options->Options->myOpt(FieldTextValue) (for example: ).

How to access this data? What would be the best approach. If you can't give me a direct solution I would be satisfied with a link to noob friendly C# tutorial on the subject.

**Isssue Resolved**

I transformed my string to XML, then converted it to a dataset and just cycled through it... Code below :)

```
List<string> entries = new List<string>();

String rawXML = item.OptBox_Options;

StringReader stream = null;
XmlTextReader reader = null;

DataSet xmlDS = new DataSet();
stream = new StringReader(rawXML);
// Load the XmlTextReader from the stream
reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
xmlDS.ReadXml(reader);

DataSet myOPTvalues = new DataSet();
myOPTvalues = xmlDS;

foreach (DataRow row in myOPTvalues.Tables[0].Rows)
{
var optItem = new PrevzemSpin();
optItem.FieldValue = row["FieldValue"].ToString();
if (optItem.FieldValue.Equals("")) optItem.FieldValue = null;

optItem.FieldTextValue = row["FieldTextValue"].ToString();
if (optItem.FieldTextValue.Equals("")) optItem.FieldTextValue = null;

entries.Add(optItem.FieldTextValue);
SpinnerValue.Tag = optItem.FieldValue;
}
```

Comment: I have posted a link to an android tutorial for xml parsing. It is quite simple to follow and implement, hope it helps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456694/mono-for-android-spinner-within-a-listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I transformed my string to XML, then converted it to a dataset and just cycled through it... Code below :)

```
List<string> entries = new List<string>();

String rawXML = item.OptBox_Options;

StringReader stream = null;
XmlTextReader reader = null;

DataSet xmlDS = new DataSet();
stream = new StringReader(rawXML);
// Load the XmlTextReader from the stream
reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
xmlDS.ReadXml(reader);

DataSet myOPTvalues = new DataSet();
myOPTvalues = xmlDS;

foreach (DataRow row in myOPTvalues.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    var optItem = new PrevzemSpin();
    optItem.FieldValue = row["FieldValue"].ToString();
    if (optItem.FieldValue.Equals("")) optItem.FieldValue = null;

    optItem.FieldTextValue = row["FieldTextValue"].ToString();
    if (optItem.FieldTextValue.Equals("")) optItem.FieldTextValue = null;

    entries.Add(optItem.FieldTextValue);
    SpinnerValue.Tag = optItem.FieldValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use xml parsing techniques such as `XmlPullParser` ,`SAX parser` or `DOM parser`.

XML Pull parser is the parser recommended in the developer's site of android [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidXML/article.html) is a tutorial for Pull parser .

Comment: Problem vas resolved a different method, but this came handy on some other issue ^_^'. Thank you for the help anyway!